# How to set the proxy settings in pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql

pgAdmin4 --version 7.8

I couldn't find where to make the settings in pgAdmin4, even though I have the latest version installed. Do you happen to know how to configure it?

I tried modifying the config.py file(%APPDATA%\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\v7\web\config.py) by adding PROXY_URL and PROXY_PORT, but it didn't work.